# In C++, do access specifiers not control visibility of static members?

Tags: c++, class, static

Code example from http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/812-static-member-functions/:

```
class Something
{
private:
    static int s_nValue;
};

int Something::s_nValue = 1;
```

This code compiles without warnings or errors. I do not understand why.

Shouldn't we get a warning for trying to access `s_nValue` because it is private? Or these access specifiers do not apply to static members?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The definition of `s_nValue` is not "accessing" the member from outside the class--it's actually its implementation.  Think of this as being just like the actual implementation of a member function, if placed in the source file outside the declaration for the enclosing class.

In other words, access specifiers absolutely apply equally to static members.

Answer (score 2):

That is the *definition* of the `private` static member of the class, and therefore it is allowed. Because the *definition* of static members of class must go outside the class, no matter whether it is `private` or `public`.

In short, it is not *accessing* the member, it is *defining* it, just like you *define* `private` functions outside the class.

Answer (score 1):

Also note: Don't get confused between Assignment and Contructors. The line:

```
int Something::s_nValue = 1;
```

Is not "assigning" a value, it's Contructing the object. In general its:

```
ClassA Something::s_nValue(...parameters...);
```

C++ allows "assignment" style syntax for Contructors. Example:

```
class A
{
public: 
    A(int i) { m_i = i; }

    int getI() { return m_i; }

private:
    int m_i;
};

class B
{
public: 
    static int getAI() { return a.getI(); }
private:
    static A a;
};

A B::a = 2;
```